# toggle between 2 iframes by clicking left and right links outside of iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

My goal is to have a button on each side of my iframe (which contains a calendar) which toggles back and forth between calendar #1 and calendar #2 in a single iframe.

Any suggestions?

```
|arrowLeft| |-----Iframe-------| |arrowRight|
```

The code works in `[http://jsfiddle.net/PauWy/447/][1]` but doesn't work when I put all the code into my website.

Why is that?

```
HTML:

<p id="toggle">
<span> Left </span>
<span> </span>
</p>

<div id="left"> <iframe>LEFT CONTENT</iframe> L</div>
<div id="right"> <iframe>RIGHT CONTENT</iframe>R </div>

<p id="toggle">
<span></span>
<span> Right </span></p>

Script:

#right { display:none; }
```

CSS:

```
$('#toggle > span').click(function() {
var ix = $(this).index();

$('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
$('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle uses jQuery. Are you including jQuery on your webpage?

Comment: On your site, open the debugger console. Are there any erors or warnings when you use that code?

Comment: You said you wanted a single `iframe` but your jsfiddle uses 2 content `div`s?

Comment: i want to toogle between the 2, so one is hidden and the other is shown. the jsfiddler code isn't mine, i want to achieve something like it

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks to use a single iFrame. So here's how I would do it using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<p id="toggle">
    <span data-src="/calendar1.html"> Left </span>
    <span data-src="/calendar2.html"> Right </span>
</p>

<iframe id="iframe" src="/calendar1.html"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#iframe');

    $('#toggle').delegate('span[data-src]', 'click', function() {
        iframe.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));            
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm, i tryed this on my site but didn't do anything, so i tryed in the jsfiddle and it didnt work there either, do i need to define some css or something?

Comment: Do you have a link to your website where it's not working and I can take a look?

Comment: I don't see anything under the slideshow. When I look into the source code none of the HTML in my example or any of the examples is there. Are you sure your html changes are being made on the web server?

Comment: here, try again, this is the code im using on it now http://jsfiddle.net/PauWy/447/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #theFrames iframe { display:none }
        #theFrames iframe:first-child { display:block }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="toggle"><span>Left</span></p>
<div id="theFrames">
    <iframe src='http://jsfiddle.net'></iframe>
    <iframe src='http://doc.jsfiddle.net'></iframe>
</div>
<p class="toggle"><span>Right</span></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=0;
    $('.toggle span').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel',a++);
    });
    $('.toggle span').click(function() {
        a = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#theFrames iframe').hide();
        $('#theFrames iframe:eq('+a+')').show();
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're just toggling two, there is no reason at all to worry about the index of the iframe elements. It's an easy show/hide situation. Don't over think it.

Comment: How so? I tested it in FF, Chrome, and IE7.

Comment: Note: jQuery, and its code is placed just before the closing body tag. Updated my answer with that note (I'm guessing that's why your code is failing)